# In-App (TabBar) Icons Show on Android but Not iOS React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I've got some icons loaded in the form of pngs that work fine in Android, and used to work on iOS, but ever since I came back to the project after a month they've disappeared on iOS only.

here's the function for the icon:

```
function CalendarIcon() {return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <Image
        source={require('./views/Assets/calendar.png')}
        style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
<Scene
  key="TeacherDash"
  component={TeacherDash}
  tabBarLabel="My Schedule "
  hideNavBar={true}
  gesturesEnabled={false}
  icon={CalendarIcon}
/>
```

I should mention I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation, and that's where the icon is being passed in.

I've tried resizing the icons, using different pngs...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What changes did you make after coming back to the project? Did you do a clean build on iOS?

Comment: Did a clean build, nothing had changed.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have a clue why, but there was something wrong with my ios folder, had to basically remove the folder and rebuild it, everything works fine now. I don't know what the actual problem was, but that was my solution.